# Can I parallelize this function?

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming, sow-reap

**Can I and should I parallelize this function ? my aim is to have faster calculations**

below is a toy function in which I kept the structure of the real function I am using. It uses `Block, Reap` and `Sow`, as well as `Do` loops, and a bunch of conditions which you do not need to understand, I just kept them in case it's important.

When I try to use things like `parallelize` or `ParallelDo`, it does not throw any error, it just doesn't return anything..

```
ass = Association[{1, 1, 1, 1} -> 0]
 Clear[func];
func[node_] :=
  Block[{resultList, tempList, hSize = Dimensions[node][[2]], 
    vSize = Dimensions[node][[1]]},
   resultList =
    Reap[
     Do[
      Do[
       tempList = node;
       If[vSize >=  i[[1]] > 0 && hSize >= i[[2]] > 0,
        Which[
          (a < 3 && i[[1]] < 3) || (4 < a && 4 < i[[1]]),
          
          Sow[ass[[Key[{node[[a, b]], node[[i[[1]], i[[2]]]], 1, 
                1}]]]];,
          5. > a > 2. && 5 > i[[1]] > 2.,
          
          Sow[ass[[Key[{node[[a, b]], node[[i[[1]], i[[2]]]], 1, 
                1}]]]];,
          (5 > a > 2 && (i[[1]] < 3 || i[[1]] > 4)),
          
          Sow[ass[[Key[{node[[a, b]], node[[i[[1]], i[[2]]]], 1, 
                1}]]]];,
          (5 > i[[1]] > 2 && (a < 3 || a > 4)),
          
          Sow[ass[[Key[{node[[a, b]], node[[i[[1]], i[[2]]]], 1, 
                1}]]]];
          ];
        ], {i, AdjacentElements[{a, b}]}]
      , {a, vSize}, {b, hSize}
      ]; e];
   resultList
   ];

func[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
1}}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

**Please don't try to use the function with any other argument, it wouldn't work**

**EDIT : code for adjacentElements**

```
  AdjacentElements[x_] := Which[
  x == {1, 1}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}}, 
  x == {1, 2}, {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}},
  x == {2, 1}, {{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}}, 
  x == {2, 2}, {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}},
  x == {3, 1}, {{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {3, 2}, {2, 2}}, 
  x == {3, 2}, {{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}},
  x == {4, 1}, {{3, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 2}}, 
  x == {4, 2}, {{3, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}},
  x == {5, 1}, {{4, 1}, {6, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}}, 
  x == {5, 2}, {{4, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {6, 2}},
  x == {6, 1}, {{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 2}}, 
  x == {6, 2}, {{5, 2}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}}]
```

Comment: It appears that `Which` evaluates the same expression regardless of which condition winds up evaluating to `True`, and so it appears the `Which` is unnecessary. Is this true?

Comment: It also might be quicker (though I'm not sure by how much) instead of `ass` to use `d = Dispatch[{{1,1,1,1} -> 0}]`, and `Replace[<your list>, d]`.

Comment: Also, I tried to run the code, but I think we also need your definition of `AdjacentElements`!

Comment: @thorimur in the actual function, the expressions are different. I am gonna edit my question with the code for AdjacentElements !

Comment: Related official post: https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/04/20/mathematica-qa-sow-reap-and-parallel-programming/